# PYTHON: JSON2XML conversion issue

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am using the json2html package to convert JSON to HTML but I am getting the error - "fork/exec /home/sftp_user/uploads/json2html.py: exec format error"

Here is what I have done

**Script is as below**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from json2html import *
from json import loads

ip = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
res = json2html.convert(json={"data":ip})
sys.stdout.write(res)
```

**The sys.argv[1] payload is below**

```
[ { "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe", "StreetName": "120 jefferson st.", "County": "Riverside", "State": " NJ", "PostCode": 8075 }, { "FirstName": "Jack", "LastName": "McGinnis", "StreetName": "220 hobo Av.", "County": "Phila", "State": " PA", "PostCode": 9119 }, { "FirstName": "John \"Da Man\"", "LastName": "Repici", "StreetName": "120 Jefferson St.", "County": "Riverside", "State": " NJ", "PostCode": 8075 }, { "FirstName": "Stephen", "LastName": "Tyler", "StreetName": "7452 Terrace \"At the Plaza\" road", "County": "SomeTown", "State": "SD", "PostCode": 91234 }, { "FirstName": null, "LastName": "Blankman", "StreetName": null, "County": "SomeTown", "State": " SD", "PostCode": 298 }, { "FirstName": "Joan \"the bone\", Anne", "LastName": "Jet", "StreetName": "9th, at Terrace plc", "County": "Desert City", "State": "CO", "PostCode": 123 } ]
```

**Error**

```
fork/exec /home/sftp_user/uploads/json2html.py: exec format error
```

Any idea on what might be the issue in the code?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error message, but I do get an error on the escape characters around John Da Man, and streetname 7452 Terrace etc.. You could try parse json as raw string by replacing that one line with this: ip = json.loads(r'{0}'.format(sys.argv[1])) and see what happens. With this line I can read and convert with json2html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting, found out that the script file name - "json2html.py" was causing the issue (conflicting with the package name - json2html). After changing the script file name, the script started working.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the problem with `null` value in your input JSON.
Try to convert it first to `None` and then it should be fine

```
from json2html import *
data = [ { "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe", "StreetName": "120 jefferson st.", "County": "Riverside", "State": " NJ", "PostCode": 8075 }, { "FirstName": "Jack", "LastName": "McGinnis", "StreetName": "220 hobo Av.", "County": "Phila", "State": " PA", "PostCode": 9119 }, { "FirstName": "John \"Da Man\"", "LastName": "Repici", "StreetName": "120 Jefferson St.", "County": "Riverside", "State": " NJ", "PostCode": 8075 }, { "FirstName": "Stephen", "LastName": "Tyler", "StreetName": "7452 Terrace \"At the Plaza\" road", "County": "SomeTown", "State": "SD", "PostCode": 91234 }, { "FirstName": None, "LastName": "Blankman", "StreetName": None, "County": "SomeTown", "State": " SD", "PostCode": 298 }, { "FirstName": "Joan \"the bone\", Anne", "LastName": "Jet", "StreetName": "9th, at Terrace plc", "County": "Desert City", "State": "CO", "PostCode": 123 } ]
res = json2html.convert(json={"data": data})
print(res)
```

Output:

```
<table border="1"><tr><th>data</th><td><table border="1"><thead><tr><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>StreetName</th><th>County</th><th>State</th><th>PostCode</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td><td>120 jefferson st.</td><td>Riverside</td><td> NJ</td><td>8075</td></tr><tr><td>Jack</td><td>McGinnis</td><td>220 hobo Av.</td><td>Phila</td><td> PA</td><td>9119</td></tr><tr><td>John &quot;Da Man&quot;</td><td>Repici</td><td>120 Jefferson St.</td><td>Riverside</td><td> NJ</td><td>8075</td></tr><tr><td>Stephen</td><td>Tyler</td><td>7452 Terrace &quot;At the Plaza&quot; road</td><td>SomeTown</td><td>SD</td><td>91234</td></tr><tr><td>None</td><td>Blankman</td><td>None</td><td>SomeTown</td><td> SD</td><td>298</td></tr><tr><td>Joan &quot;the bone&quot;, Anne</td><td>Jet</td><td>9th, at Terrace plc</td><td>Desert City</td><td>CO</td><td>123</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></table>
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting the error even if there are no NULLS in the payload. FYI I am using an RPA tool to call the python script.

Comment: Most likely your RPA tool corrputs JSON file. Add json validation to your script before convert it to HTML.